# Defining the width/height of a GridSpec in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple plot to compare some images as in:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True,figsize=(15,15))
gs = GridSpec(3,2, figure=fig)
axes = []

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax.imshow(square, cmap='gray')
ax.set_title('Original')
axes.append(ax)

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
im1 = ax.imshow(scaled_square_sobel, cmap='gray')
ax.set_title('Sobel')
axes.append(ax)

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
im2 = ax.imshow(scaled_square_sobel_x, cmap='gray')
ax.set_title('Sobel X')
axes.append(ax)

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax.imshow(scaled_square_sobel_y, cmap='gray')
ax.set_title('Sobel Y')
axes.append(ax)

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,0:2])
fig.colorbar(im2, cax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
plt.suptitle('Comparacao Sobel');
```

That looks like this

[image: Weird colorbar]

As you can see the colorbar takes the height of the full plot instead a nice and elegant small height. How can I "force" a GridSpec to have a pre-defined height.

Of course I could create a (30,20) grid spec and define each plot to a larger slice, but IMHO this is also not elegant, and seems I'm working with HTML tables.

Any ideas to improve the code above?

Comment: you want to use the `height_ratios` parameter. i've explained in the tutorial here: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-gridspec-py

Comment: thanks, can you write a quick answer just to fulfill SO mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to make a gridspec for the colorbar:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True,figsize=(15,15))

# other axes...

ax = axs[1, 1]
im2 = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(10,10), cmap='gray')
ax.set_title('Sobel Y')

fig.colorbar(im2, ax=axs, orientation='horizontal')
```